# NPM build script keeps re-executing

Tags: node.js, npm

I use npm as a build tool, my scripts section looks like:

```
"scripts": {
"clean": "rm './build/+(css|js)/*'",
"watch:js": "watch 'npm run build:js' ./app/js",
"prebuild:js" : "rimraf ./build/js && mkdirp ./build/js",
"build:js": "browserify ./app/js/app.js -t [ babelify --presets es2015 ] -d | exorcist ./build/js/bundle.js.map | uglifyjs -c > ./build/js/bundle.js",
"watch:css": "watch 'npm run build:css' ./app/stylesheets",
"prebuild:css" : "rimraf ./build/css && mkdirp ./build/css",
"build:css": "cssimport ./app/stylesheets/app.css | cssmin > ./build/css/bundle.css",
"build": "npm run build:js && npm run build:css",
"build:watch": "parallelshell 'npm run watch:js' 'npm run watch:css'",
"watch:node": "nodemon ./app/server.js",
"start:dev": "npm run build:watch && npm run watch:node",
"start:prod": ""
 },
```

now when I change a js file in `./app/js` the `(pre)build:js` executes succesfully once.

but when I change a css file in `./app/stylesheets` the `(pre)build:css` executes three times, succesfully?!

output looks like:

> myapp@0.0.1 prebuild:css /home/me/dev/myapp
>   rimraf ./build/css && mkdirp ./build/css
>
> myapp@0.0.1 build:css /home/me/dev/myapp
>   cssimport ./app/stylesheets/app.css | cssmin > ./build/css/bundle.css
>
> myapp@0.0.1 prebuild:css /home/me/dev/myapp
>   rimraf ./build/css && mkdirp ./build/css
>
> myapp@0.0.1 build:css /home/me/dev/myapp
>   cssimport ./app/stylesheets/app.css | cssmin > ./build/css/bundle.css
>
> myapp@0.0.1 prebuild:css /home/me/dev/myapp
>   rimraf ./build/css && mkdirp ./build/css
>
> myapp@0.0.1 build:css /home/me/dev/myapp
>   cssimport ./app/stylesheets/app.css | cssmin > ./build/css/bundle.css

I don't understand why it would do that, ive tried using an alternatives for `cssimport` and `cssmin` but the same happens.

**UPDATE**

I replaced `parallelshell` with `concurrently` and now when I change css when its running, I get:

> [1]
>
> [1] > myapp@0.0.1 prebuild:css /home/me/myapp
>
> [1] > rimraf ./build/css && mkdirp ./build/css
>
> [1]
>
> [1]
>
> [1] > myapp@0.0.1 build:css /home/me/myapp
>
> [1] > cssimport ./app/stylesheets/app.css | cssmin > ./build/css/bundle.css
>
> [1]
>
> myapp@0.0.1 prebuild:css /home/me/myapp
>   rimraf ./build/css && mkdirp ./build/css
>
> myapp@0.0.1 build:css /home/me/myapp
>   cssimport ./app/stylesheets/app.css | cssmin > ./build/css/bundle.css
>
> myapp@0.0.1 prebuild:css /home/me/myapp
>   rimraf ./build/css && mkdirp ./build/css
>
> myapp@0.0.1 build:css /home/me/myapp
>   cssimport ./app/stylesheets/app.css | cssmin > ./build/css/bundle.css

so it seems that outside of the css task `watch:css` (which is `[1]`) the `build:css` task is executed twice more, but I only execute the task with `concurrently`, so how can it be that it executes outside of `concurrently`??

Comment: looks like an async problem

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: the TL;DR version is you have to implement callbacks to tell node when things finish. I would suggest using gulp if you can it makes solving the problem much easier.

Comment: thanks for the comment. nah gonna stay away from gulp, trying to keep it small